# How to limit data in Eloquent? Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am manipulating a database with more than 45 thousand records, I need to do an update, passing data from one table to another, but every time I pass the data, my CLI stops working. Any suggestions on how to manipulate these data in a smoother way? I saw some articles talking about using offset, but I could not apply it to my case.

```
    $erp = Product::all();
    OCProduct::where('product_id', '!=', 0)
        ->update(['model' => $erp->erp_model]);
```

Comment: What is the logic of your update?

Comment: Sorry, I mistook the columns, now I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have an issue with your code.  `$erp` would be a `Collection` so it wouldn't contain an `erp_model` attribute.  You'd have to traverse that collection and grab `erp_model` for each instance of `Product` and do your update.

With that said, I can only guess what you are trying to do but it's pretty clear why you are crashing.  If you have 45,000 records, you are trying to store that all in a variable in PHP, and then trying to run queries on it.  It would be much better to just allow your database to handle everything via a single update query.

```
UPDATE oc_products
INNER JOIN products ON oc_products.product_id = products.id
SET oc_products.model = products.erp_model
WHERE oc_products.product_id <> 0;
```

Comment: But would not that overwhelm my code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  It's just off loading the work from PHP onto the Database which was designed for exactly these situations.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.